# How to add countable numbers in Html tables

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ado.net

I want to add s.no in my table using table.append but it doesn't add in my table here is me code please help me out.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Users.FirstName,Users.Address,UserFees.MonthName,UserFees.BookNumber,UserFees.Date,UserFees.Year,UserFees.TotalPaid,UserFees.Balance from Users inner join UserFees on Users.UserID=UserFees.UserID", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            table.Append("<table class='table table-bordered table-hover table-striped'>");
            table.Append("<tr><th>S.NO</th><th>Address</th><th>Month</th><th>Book Number</th><th>Date</th><th>Year</th><th>Total Paid</th><th>Balance</th>");
            table.Append("</tr>");
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int i = 1;


                    table.Append("<tbody>");
                    table.Append("<tr class='success'>");
                    table.Append("<td>" i++ "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + reader[1] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + reader[2] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + reader[3] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + reader[4] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + reader[5] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + reader[6] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + reader[7] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("</tr>");
                    table.Append("</tbody>");
                }
            }
            table.Append("</table>");
            PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = table.ToString() });
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is  column in this I call  variable i++ but s.no not countable.

Comment: Please use tags properly. This question has nothing to do with asp.net-mvc

Comment: You are adding `tbody` on every iteration, while you really need it just once. Moreover, since you are not using `thead` tag, use of `tr` and `tbody` on the same level is wrong, so I'd suggest you get rid of `tbody` altogether

Comment: please give some example.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, @Andrei is saying that you need to remove the statements: `table.Append("<tbody>");` and `table.Append("</tbody>");` from your code. You could either move it so it surrounds the `while` loop, or simply remove the statements completely.

Comment: @JerodJohnson, that's right, and I would actually recommend to remove it completely, as having `tr` and `tbody` on the same level is incorrect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody#Usage_context

Comment: And the row number will always be 2. You reset it with every loop of the `while` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the plus signs, like:

```
table.Append("<td>" + i++ +"</td>");
```

if it still doesn't work you may try:

```
table.Append("<td>" + (i++).ToString() +"</td>");
```

---

Edit:

I just realized you are iterating wrong as well, I'd change the iteration like this and see what happens:

```
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            int i = 1;
            table.Append("<tbody>");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                table.Append("<tr class='success'>");
                table.Append("<td>"+ i++ + "</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + reader[1] + "</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + reader[2] + "</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + reader[3] + "</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + reader[4] + "</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + reader[5] + "</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + reader[6] + "</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + reader[7] + "</td>");
                table.Append("</tr>");
            }
            table.Append("</tbody>");
        }
```

Notice I took the "i" initialization and the tbody out of the loop.

Regarding what others are saying about having < tbody > and < tr > together, I don't know about "rules" but I know they work together, I use them like that all the time.

Hope this helps